# Sum of minimum values from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written a simple C++ program to find the minimum sum values of an array. I have `arr[12] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16,32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048}`. I want to count how many minimum values from that array to fulfil `int p`. For example, `p = 10`, There's 2 index with minimum values that fulfill integer p, which is `arr[1] = 2`and `arr[3] = 8`. I solved this problem with some kind binary conversion method. I save these binaries into new array `arr2[]` and sum all of that binaries so I get the answer 2 in the example. But I encounter a problem, if the input is `p = 1024`, for some reason array values in second for loop not saving `int m` value from the first for loop. This only applies on 1024, not on other input (or not to be found yet).Can someone explain why this is happening?. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
 int t, p, c=0;
 int arr[12] = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048};
 int arr2[c];
 scanf("%d", &t);
 while(t--)
 {
  int sum = 0, m = 0;
  scanf("%d", &p);
  for(int i = 11; i>=0; i--)
  {            
    m = p/arr[i];
    p = p - m*arr[i];                                                        
    arr2[i] = m;
    printf("%d ", m); 
  }
  printf("\n");
  for(int i = 11; i>=0; i--)
  {
    sum+=arr2[i];
    printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
  }
  printf("\n SUM : %d \n", sum);
 }
getch();
}
```

I think I have a simple mistake, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: `int arr2[c];` is wrong.

Comment: can you explain why is that wrong?

Comment: 1. Variable lenght arrays aren't standard c++. 2. `c` is `0` at the time the array is created. Accessing it leads to _undefined behavior_.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined for all input values, not just 1024.   The fact you're only getting symptoms for input of values of 1024 is happenstance - one feature of undefined behaviour is that the behaviour is permitted to seem correct.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I change the variable c value as @Shirish suggest. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the value of c=0 to c=12, as I can see your arr2 array will be holding 12 values, one for each occurrences of values from arr array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Shirish now it works. I was right that I must've had simple mistake :D